# Requesting to get shared drive List id and drive name in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D92Eh.jpg)Drive.Drives.List this method only retrived 10 shared Drive List and not able to retrieve all the Drive List in google apps script.

Please find my below code for your reference.

I need list of drive id and list of drive name but I am getting only 10 drive id and name not all the list.

```
function driveList()
{
const sharedDrive = Drive.Drives.list().items
  .map(drive => ({id:drive.id,name:drive.name}));

drivedata=JSON.stringify(sharedDrive);
driveList=JSON.parse(drivedata);
for(var i=0;i<driveList.length;i++)
{
    Logger.log(driveList[i].id);
    Logger.log(driveList[i].name);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update with a third possible reason**

It's probably one of the three reasons:

1. You need to paginate; if [your result has a `nextPageToken` property](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list), you need to go to the next page and get more results, and continue doing so while you still get a `nextPageToken`. You likely want to use the `do while` loop here to make sure your request executes at least once.
2. You simply don't have access to those other shared folders and might want to be check if don't have a multi-login issue.
3. `Drives.list` retrieves shared **Drives** and not shared **folders**. Given that you are using both terms interchangeably, the third possibility is that you are expecting folders but getting drives instead

Comment: I have access to all the shared folders.I used next page token and getting the same 10 folder id recurrently.Please update any comments

Comment: please update the question with your code, not a photograph of your screen

Comment: Also, `Drives.list` retrieves shared **Drives** and not shared folders. Given that you are using both terms interchangibly, the third possibility is that you are expecting folders and getting drives instead

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I need list of drive id and list of drive name and I am getting only 10 drive list recurrently.
Please update any comments

Comment: Only when you properly share your code, as I had asked. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: I have added my code and please upadate any comments

Comment: There is no pagination

Comment: Please explain how to use pagination in google apps script

Comment: You said you used nextPageToken, but it's not in your code. What did you mean you used it?